# How should I handle this situation in FireBase where two users go for same Database key

Tags: android, race-condition, firebase-security

I´m saving items called `Street` using the FireBase `push` and get a list of `Street` items with auto generated ids right. Lets say each `Street` have a node like `"path" : "unique value"`. Let´s say two users are about to insert a new `Street` that has the same `"path" : "unique value"`.

What is an appropriate way to eliminate this from happening? It´s like a web-shop where user puts an item in the basket, and the system behind now have to reserve this item until user buy it.

Should I create a separate FireBase root like "reserved_streets" and let user add his reserved `Street` along with user.id until he buy it? Maybe have a Servlet instance running removing entries that are 10 min old.

The `Street` list can be very big, maybe 100 millions in rar cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to prevent duplicate values in the Firebase Database is to convert those values into keys.

So if you current model is (next time, please share such a minimal snippet in your question please):

```
streets: {
  "-K1234567": {
    path: "unique path"
  },
  "-K1234568": {
    path: "unique path 2"
  }
}
```

You would add an additional structure (or change the existing structure) that uses the paths as keys:

```
pathsToStreets: {
  "unique path": "-K1234567",
  "unique path 2": "-K1234568"
}
```

With this structure there is guaranteed to be only one street for a path and you can use security rules that the path can't be overwritten.

Comment: My God this is elegant

Comment: But until the `street` is created, yes of course User while putting his `street` in the basket must also add his street to `pathsToStreets`. Now other Users can check the  `pathsToStreets` and see if the `street` is reserved. If first user go ahead and buy then the `street` - "-K1234567" will be created. My God time for a donat

Comment: But what if first User don´t buy the `street` and he don´t remove the entry from `pathsToStreets` because device crash or system failure. Maybe having a Servlet instance running removing entries. What do you think?

Comment: You could require a multi-location update and then use security rules to enforce that. Having a server may be simpler at first glance, but doing this without server-side code is also feasible.